# To populate data from different sheets to another sheet by clicking on drop down list

Tags: excel, list, ms-office, dropdown

In my workbook I have 3 sheets named "NAME1', 'NAME2' AND 'MAIN'.

In this main sheet I have a drop downlist which is named as NAME1 AND NAME2.

If I choose NAME1 from drop down list I need to display all content from sheet name1. same for name2 too How can I do this?

Comment: display where in Main sheet? What have you tried? Sounds like you might want formulas using INDIRECT.

Answer (score 0):

With the drop-down in cell **A1** of the `MAIN` worksheet, the formula:

```
=INDIRECT(A1 & "!B9")
```

will display the contents of cell **B9** from the indicated worksheet.

Comment: Is that possible to show the contents from cell B9 to D15